# Is there any opensource 2d open-world simulation with python API?

Tags: getting-started, software-evaluation

For my pet project I’m looking for a grid-like world simulation with some kind of resources that requires from agent incrementally intelligent behaviour to survive.

Something like [this steam game](https://store.steampowered.com/app/396890/Gridworld/), but with API.  I’ve seen [minecraft fork](https://github.com/Microsoft/malmo), but it’s too complex for my task. There is [pycolab](https://github.com/deepmind/pycolab), i can build some world on this engine, but I’d prefer ready-to-use simulations.

Is there any option? I'll appreciate any suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try [Mesa](https://github.com/projectmesa/mesa).

It has [various examples](https://github.com/projectmesa/mesa/tree/master/examples) that are commonly-used in agent-based modelling, like Epstein's model, a wolf/sheep predator/prey model, and many more.

There is also an [introductory tutorial](http://mesa.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/intro_tutorial.html).